# Python creating textfile file in a specific folder

Tags: python-3.x

i'm trying to to get my script to create a text file and have it in a folder called ouput and seem to be unable to get it to work,

This is what i got at the moment, how do i get it to make the script at in a specific folder?

```
f = open("C:/Users/User/TestScript/Output" + input1 + "Username", "w")
f.write(data)
f.close()
```

Comment: Does the folder exist? Are there any error messages? What is the value of `input1`?

Comment: Folder exists, no error message just creates a file with the name "Output" same as the folder name, input1 is userinput in a text widget from tkinter

Comment: What do you get when you print `input1`?

Comment: Usually the user puts in a Node name, like TT0505 and the text file gets named TT0505_Username